# Why "{} || {}" throws syntax error?

Tags: javascript

This works:

```
var a = {} || {};
```

While this does not:

```
{} || {};
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ||
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Why is that?
Tested on ff and chrome.

Comment: When `{` is the first token in a new statement, the parser expects to see a block (compound) statement; a list of statements inside `{ }`.  In your first sample, the first token in the statement is `var`, so the `{` is interpreted as the start of an object initializer expression.

Answer (score 7):

Javascript considers braces to be a code block. Try this:

```
({} || {});
```

Answer (score 5):

Because in `{} || {};`, the first `{}` is *not* interpreted as an [empty] object.  It's interpreted as a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

Try this:

```
({}) || {};
```